# Can I force powershell to ignore mouse input?

Tags: powershell

I'm running a basic Powershell script on a remote server, and while it's running, it ignores keyboard input completely.  This is intended.  When, however, you click anywhere in the Powershell window, it stops input until you clear the pause with a keypress.

Is there some way I can force Powershell to ignore mouse input altogether while the script is running?  I want this to be as difficult to close as possible, ie. you need to actually click X to close the window, or kill the process, or the like.

Running in a Command Prompt window instead is acceptable, but I'd rather run it in the Powershell GUI instead if possible.

Comment: You mean the PowerShell ISE? The only significant difference between "the Command Prompt window" and the PowerShell command window is the size and color.

Comment: PowerShell doesn't have a GUI.  GUI means "Graphical User Interface".  PowerShell provides a CLI - Command Line Interface.  Maybe a bit nitpicky, but it's driving me crazy about your question.

Comment: You're both right.  I foolishly believed that the default color palette, summary text at the top of the screen, and different launch method meant it was a seperate executable.  Thanks for the knowledge!

Comment: Your description sounds a bit weird - are you using Remote Desktop? Could you, instead, use PowerShell on your local computer and use remoting to launch the script on the remote computer with no UI visible at all? Otherwise, have you considered http://stackoverflow.com/q/1802127/478656 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disable 'Quick-Edit' mode for your powershell console.

[image: quick edit is crap.]

Comment: While this certainly answers my question, is there a way to disable it for certain scripts only?  I can definitely see circumstances where being able to copy/paste things out of the console output might be useful.

What I'm saying is, being a script-level change would be useful.  If not, I can make a seperate shortcut to powershell for "editable" and "noneditable" scripts.

Comment: I haven't found a way, and have looked quite a bit.  But that doesn't mean a way doesn't exist.  Feel free to update your question to include that requirement.

Comment: Gotcha.  I think the "two shortcuts to Powershell" option is the best choice here.  Thank you for your assistance :)